# compare a string with an array php

Tags: arrays, string, compare

I made this function:

```
 <?php
function check() {
    if ($GLOBALS['a'] == $GLOBALS['tools']) {

    echo "HETZELFDE! <br>";
   var_dump($GLOBALS['a']);
  echo "<br>";
   var_dump($GLOBALS['tools']);

}
else {

    $GLOBALS['tools'];
    echo "NIET HETZELFDE <br>";

    $GLOBALS['a'] = strtoupper(array2string($GLOBALS['a']));
    var_dump($GLOBALS['a']     );
   echo "<br>";
    //array2string($GLOBALS['a']);
    var_dump($GLOBALS['tools']     );   

}
}

check() ?>
```

the result is:

```
NIET HETZELFDE
string(63) "[0] => RED [1] => BLUE [2] => BLACK [3] => ORANGE [4] => GREEN "
string(58) "[RED] => [BLUE] => [BLACK] => [ORANGE] => [GREEN] => "
```

what i need is to know if $a == $tools (if a is the same as tools)

how can i do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use array_diff to know if the arrays has any difference.

Example of array_diff()

```
<?php
$array1    = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2    = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

The result:
Array
(
    [b] => brown
    [c] => blue
    [0] => red
)

If you want to compare the array index , you can use array_diff_assoc()

```
<?php
$array1    = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
$array2    = array("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$resultado = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
print_r($resultado);
?>
```

the result

Array
(
    [b] => brown
    [c] => blue
    [0] => red
)